# How to create a class name with current users roles?

Tags: css, wordpress, roles

My site have 15 users roles. How to create a class name with current users roles ?

i want class like this

```
<span class="usr-level roles" </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

      if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
          foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
              $user_role = $role;
      }
    }
    else{
        $user_role = "your default class";
    }
```

Then just print the $user_role in class

```
<span class="<?php echo $user_role; ?>" </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the user role with a function: for example

```
function display_user_roles(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = implode(', ', $user_info->roles);
    return $user_roles;
}
```

then check role and set a class :

```
$x_role= display_user_roles();

switch ($x_role) {
    case 'x':
        $class_role = 'x';
        break;
    case 'y':
        $class_role = 'y';
        break;
    case 'z':
        $class_role = 'z';
        break;
}
```